# Plot2d: nothing to plot for error when attempting to plot with wximplicit_plot

Tags: math, maxima, wxmaxima

I am using wxmaxima 23.12.0 and Maxima 5.47.0 on macOS 13.5. I have successfully plotted using `wximplicit_plot` using the following:

```
wximplicit_plot(x^2+y^2=1, [x,-2,2], [y,-2,2], same_xy);
```

but when I try the following:

```
load(implicit_plot);

set_plot_option(same_xy);

line:y=3*x-5;
circle:x^2-6*x+y^2-8*y+22=0;

wximplicit_plot([line, circle], [x,0,5], [y,0,5]);
implicit_plot is now obsolete. Using plot2d instead:
"plot2d ([y = 3*x-5,y^2-8*y+x^2-6*x+22 = 0] = 0, [x,0,5], [y,0,5], [plot_format,gnuplot], [gnuplot_term,pngcairo], [gnuplot_preamble,"set terminal pngcairo dashed background \"white\" enhanced font \"arial,10\" fontscale 1.0 size 1200,900; set zeroaxis;; "], [gnuplot_out_file,"/var/folders/8b/b7l3tsmx2vz8559ln8sl1h080000gn/T/maxout_13645_2.png"])"
plot2d: nothing to plot for [y = 3*x-5,y^2-8*y+x^2-6*x+22 = 0] = 0.
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

But if I use `plot2d` passing in the same arguments as above it works.

Can anyone spot if I have missed anything in the way I am calling wximplicit_plot?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The behavior you observed is a bug in `implicit_plot`. `implicit_plot` has been superseded by an implicit plot capability in `plot2d`, so a separate function isn't needed; `implicit_plot` is supposed to fix up its arguments and call `plot2d`, and that wasn't being handled correctly. See: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/4237/ I fixed the bug already, but that won't appear until the next released version; my advice is to just call `plot2d` directly and don't bother with `implicit_plot` anymore.

Comment: Thank so much for taking the time to let me know, it's stopped me going in circles! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, that observed behavior is a bug in Maxima:

- Bug report #4237 (2024-01-02): [implicit_plot punting to plot2d implicit fails when argument is a list of equations](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/4237/)
- Fixed in commit 65bc09 (2024-01-02): [implicit_plot: when first argument is a list, create equations one by one before punting to plot2d.](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/65bc099cc573cff26035a64384fdd0c36409d681/)

As a workaround, use `wxplot2d` instead of `wximplicit_plot`:

```
set_plot_option(same_xy)$

line:y=3*x-5;
circle:x^2-6*x+y^2-8*y+22=0;

wxplot2d([line, circle], [x,0,5], [y,0,5]);
```

Result in wxMaxima:

[image: wxMaxima wxplot2d]